# qt creator using git: You did not checkout a branch

Tags: git, qt-creator

I have recently started using qt creator. When I created my first project I was asked if I wanted to use git for version control - I agreed.

Now I want to commit my work. However when I try to do so from qt creator (Tools -> Git -> Commit) I get the message:

```
You did not checkout a branch
```

What do I need to do on order to commit my changes? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try Tools->Git->Local Repository->Branches... Then select the branch (probably called master or origin) and select "Checkout"

Comment: @Merlin069: Thanks for the tip. However when I try this (I do not have LocalRepository, but I have Branches) I get the branch 'master', but I cannot check it out :(. I have the impression this was created when I was trying to commit from the command line. Can that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to check-out the 'master' branch. The branch you check out is the one that you're working on. Have you staged your files before trying to commit them?

Comment: I have, actually I was asked every time I added a new file to the project whether I want to add it to the repository. When I to a status query I get a list of files tagged "new file", some "modified" but not staged for commit and some untracked files (which is ok, as I do not need them at the moment). I have also staged my main program in the Qt creator. Still I cannot commit, nor can I checkout a branch ...

Comment: Can you create a new branch? If so, try create a new one, check it out and see if you can then check out the main branch.

Comment: This is driving me mad! I have created a new branch. But still I cannot commit, neither the new branch nor the old master when I check that one out again :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71242/discussion-between-merlin069-and-red-tiger).